# Modifying an object causes the modifications to be reflected in a copy of that object previously pushed to an array

Tags: javascript, object

I have code similar to the following

```
var l_mattes_array = [];
var matte_array = [];
var mattes = [];
mattes[0] = "<test><imgsrc>test1</imgsrc></test>";
mattes[1] = "<test><imgsrc>test2</imgsrc></test>";
$(mattes).each(function(i, el)
{
  matte_array.imgsrc = ($(el).find("imgsrc").first().text());
  l_mattes_array[i] = matte_array;
  console.log(l_mattes_array[i]);
});
console.log(l_mattes_array);
```

The output I am getting is:

```
[imgsrc: "test1"]
[imgsrc: "test2"]

(2) [Array(0), Array(0)]
0:[imgsrc: "test2"]
1:[imgsrc: "test2"]
```

The output I want:
    [imgsrc: "test1"]
    [imgsrc: "test2"]

```
(2) [Array(0), Array(0)]
0:[imgsrc: "test1"]
1:[imgsrc: "test2"]
```

Comment: You’re mutating the same `matte_array`, so `matte_array.imgsrc` will always refer to the same object.

Comment: @Xufox In hindsight, it may be that easy, but if you don't already have an understanding of reference types, this statement doesn't help much at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `matte_array` is a reference type (all objects are, and arrays are objects, so yes). What this means is, when you say `l_matte_array[i] = matte_array`, you are actually setting that index of `l_matte_array` to a reference to the value of the array `matte_array`, and then when you modify the `matte_array` again in the second iteration, you are modifying the value referenced by `matte_array`, that value is the same value that you set `l_matte_array[i]` to refer to in the preceding iteration.

So all your `l_matte_array` indices are merely holding a reference to a single shared value, and you have modified that value to have its `imgsrc` property be equal to `"test2"`.

Go read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) MDN article, you will come out of it having a nice understanding of JavaScript datatypes.

Another problem with you code is, you are using an array as an object, which is inappropriate. Use an array if you want to take advantage of its functionality of having numerically indexed elements; if you want to group some properties and/or methods somewhere, just use a normal object (created with a literal: `var obj = {}`); if you want something to hold a single value, use a variable.

So, I solved your problem in the following way (I am not using a variable for `imgsrc` because I believe you are modifying the objects that hold `imgsrc` sometime later in your code, if you are not adding any properties/methods to the objects that you push to `l_mattes_array`, just replace my object with an `imgsrc` variable):

```js
var l_mattes_array = [];
    var mattes = [];

    mattes[0] = "<test><imgsrc>test1</imgsrc></test>";
    mattes[1] = "<test><imgsrc>test2</imgsrc></test>";

    $(mattes).each(function(i, el) {
      var matte_object = {};
      matte_object.imgsrc = ($(el).find("imgsrc").first().text());
      l_mattes_array[i] = matte_object;
    });

    console.log(l_mattes_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and remove all html tags with the regular expression `/<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g`.

Code:

```js
const mattes = ['<test><imgsrc>test1</imgsrc></test>', '<test><imgsrc>test2</imgsrc></test>'];
const l_mattes_array = mattes.map(el => ({imgsrc: el.replace(/<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g, '')}));

console.log(l_mattes_array);
```

Comment: This is the same thing as doing homework for a student instead of pushing them in the right direction.

Comment: @Taurus I don't understand your comment? I should explain more?

Comment: @Yosvel_Quintero I appreciate you providing another solution, but the problem roots from the fact that OP doesn't really know anything about an essential part of JS: data types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're referencing the same object (`matte_array`), so you're changing the `src` property but the reference is still the same. What you could to is just initialize `matte_array` inside the cycle, so each time it becomes a new array, like this:

```
// ...
// var matte_array = []; // Should not be here
// ...
$(mattes).each(function(i, el)
{
  var matte_array = []; // Should be here
  // ...
});
// ...
```

Here you have a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6j73wgdw/

Answer (score -1):

I added

```
matte_array = [];
```

after adding to `l_mattes_array` and that fixed it

Comment: That fixes the problem at hand, but only until you run into the problem again (do you know why this solved your problem ?). With this solution, you are only postponing the inevitable: a good understanding of JavaScript data types. Also, your existing code has some flaws. All this obligates me to say "read my answer if you will".